# if statement is not running even if condition is true

Tags: python, if-statement

the if condition is not running even if the condition is true. On line 29 there's a function set_row and on line 31 there's a function set_col. On Line 58 there's an if statement which checks if guess_row1 is equals to set_row and guess_col1=set_col even the condition is true if statement does not run else always run

```
from random import randint
user1 = {
    "name":input("Enter your name"),
    "board":[]
}
user2 = {
    "name":input("Enter your name"),
    "board":[]
}

def set_board(user):
    for x in range(5):
        user["board"].append(["O"]*5)

def print_board(user):
    for row in user["board"]:
        print(" ".join(row))
print("")
print("Let's start")
print("")
set_board(user1)
set_board(user2)
print("This is {}'s board".format(user1["name"]))
print_board(user1)
print("")
print("This is {}'s board".format(user2["name"]))
print_board(user2)

def set_row(user1):
    return randint(0, len(user1["board"])-1)
def set_col(user1):
    return randint(0, len(user1["board"])-1)

print("")
print("Answer for {}".format(user1["name"]))
print(set_row(user1))
print(set_col(user1))
print("")
def set_row2(user2):
    return randint(0, len(user2["board"])-1)
def set_col2(user2):
    return  randint(0, len(user2["board"])-1)
print("Answer for {}".format(user2["name"]))

print(set_row2(user2))
print(set_col2(user2))


print("")
for turnu1 in range(3,0,-1):
    print("turn's left for {} ".format(user1["name"]) + str(turnu1))
    print("")
    guess_row1 = int(input("Enter the row "))
    guess_col1 = int(input("Enter the col "))
    print("")
    if guess_row1==set_row(user1) and guess_col1==set_col(user1):
        print("your right")
    else:
        print("Wrong answer")
```

Comment: If the statement doesnt run then you can be sure that the condition is false even though you *think* it to be true.

Comment: Every time you call set_col a new number is generated. You can't compare it to what the earlierer call returned unless you store the value.

Comment: So how do you know that the answer is right? You are never printing the randomly picked value, nor are you storing it anywhere for you to verify that you got it right.

Comment: i am calling the function set_row and set_col only once can you point me to the line where you think i am calling the function again

Comment: @JaskaranSingh: you are not. Nor do you store the return value. How do you know that the guess is correct then?

Comment: i am printing it on line 36 and 37 @MartijnPieters

Comment: @JaskaranSingh: no, those are **different** random numbers. Those are random numbers generated before. When you call `set_row()` and `set_col()` in the `if` statement, **new** random numbers are produced. You won't get the numbers you printed, because you are running the function again so `randint()` is run again and these will not just return what was returned before. Then they wouldn't be random.

Comment: these numbers are random... store them on creation otherwise they will always be different every time you call your functon

Comment: ok thank you @MartijnPieters i found my mistake i should store the random number in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call and print the random numbers for user 2:

```
print(set_row2(user2))
print(set_col2(user2))
```

then those numbers are generated by `randint()` and never stored anywhere.

The calls for user 1 then will be **new** random numbers:

```
if guess_row1==set_row(user1) and guess_col1==set_col(user1):
```

and not correspond with the first set of calls. If you meant those to be equal, then *store* the random values you picked first:

```
user2_row = set_row2(user2)
user2_col = set_col2(user2)
```

so you can test against them later:

```
if guess_row1 == user2_row and guess_col1 == user2_col:
```